# VBA Data Label Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I cant get my chart Data labels to be formatted automatically using VBA. I tried setting them manually, but since I'm using a dynamic range (chart_range_1), every time I run my macro, the data label formatting/font get reset to default

```
With ActiveSheet
   chart_range_1 = "A10:B" & lastRow
   Set chrt1 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
   chrt1.SetSourceData Source:=Range(chart_range_1)'
End With
     
chrt1.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
chrt1.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabel.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"
```

Comment: I don't think a `Series` has a `DataLabel` property, looks like `DataLabels` from the docs. That last line doesn't throw an error?

Comment: Run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: As I said, `Series` doesn't have a `DataLabel` property.

Comment: chrt1.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"  changed it to DataLabels. and now got error 445

Comment: What code does the macro recorder produce if you apply the number format manually?

Comment: ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Selection.ShowValue = True
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"

Comment: chrt1.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)" Tried this, but still getting the same error